# how to get user photos from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

Here's my code so far:

```
/// after login
Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
params1.putString("fields", "id, name, link");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/albums", params1, new AlbumsRequestListener());
...
public class AlbumsRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.e("PHOTOS",response);
    }   
}
```

and it returns

> 12-24 18:20:16.738: ERROR/PHOTOS(8170):
>   {"data":[{"id":"301187506586589","name":"photos","link":"http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=301187506586589&id=100000860254064&aid=65054","created_time":"2011-12-24T16:00:09+0000"},{"id":"299723973399609","name":"Wall
>   Photos","link":"http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=299723973399609&id=100000860254064&aid=64756","created_time":"2011-12-21T22:16:53+0000"},{"id":"299722003399806","name":"Profile
>   Pictures","link":"http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=299722003399806&id=100000860254064&aid=64755","created_time":"2011-12-21T22:12:39+0000"}],"paging":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=AAAELP9dblyEBAHgW3q8jkepd16GRnD9iDoGW0rhPYH6LxVa13ccQH6yV9sWyo8k5FBA7m15TnzlyXyIasbltJZC422ox7W34t1drDiQZDZD&format=json&fields=id,+name,+link&limit=25&since=1324742409&__paging_token=301187506586589&__previous=1","next":"https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=AAAELP9dblyEBAHgW3q8jkepd16GRnD9iDoGW0rhPYH6LxVa13ccQH6yV9sWyo8k5FBA7m15TnzlyXyIasbltJZC422ox7W34t1drDiQZDZD&format=json&fields=id,+name,+link&limit=25&until=1324505559&__paging_token=299722003399806"}}

Now the question is - how to I get direct links to photos out of this? How do I make a request to get a photo or... well, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706678/fetch-photos-from-facebook-album-in-android  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994508/cant-add-comments-to-photos-in-facebook-android-application

Comment: What facebook premisions did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JSONArray` to get out links and other stuff

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag"," "+json_data.getString("link"));

                }
```

Good luck:)